# Angular - Scaling an inline d3 SVG created in code

Tags: angular, svg, d3.js, scale

This is my first question here, so I apologise if I mess something up.

I'm building a simple SVG in Angular using the d3 library, but I can't get the thing to scale.

I did a whole bunch of reading up on SVG's over here https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ and I chose to go with the approach of building the SVG within a `viewbox` and then applying the `width` and `height` attributes.

When inspecting the SVG, I see that it takes up the specified `100px` for the `width` and `height`, but the `SVGElements` themselves are still the original size.

BUT! If, instead of setting the `width` and `height` through code, I modify the `width` and `height` by editing the SVG as HTML in `Dev Tools` (ie: `width="100px" height="100px"`), then it scales perfectly!

I've made a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/kYcTocJzi6eA59Yj?preview - The first SVG sets the `width` and `height` through code, whereas the second SVG doesn't have them set so that you can try it out in `Dev Tools` if need be :)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox), **viewBox** is camelCased, but you typed view**b**ox:

```
const svg2 = d3.select(this.svgContainerRef2.nativeElement)
  .append('svg')
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${circleRadius * 2} ${circleRadius * 2}`);
```

Comment: Oh my word, I'm _that_ guy that didn't spot a silly mistake :'( And I was so careful with in all the other places I used it, like `xMinYMin`!. Thanks so much :)